# Connection error when using AWS RDS proxy

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora, amazon-rds-proxy

I had setup RDS proxy for an Aurora DB cluster and I am getting the following error while connecting. Note that I am able to connect to the original DB cluster without any issue. I checked the security groups, they look fine (Both proxy and DB are same security group and There is rule that allows 3306 from self). I verified the credentials in AWS Secrets Manager, It also looks fine. Did any one face this issue ?

***Lost connection to MySQL server at 'handshake: reading initial communication packet', system error: 11***

Answer (score 6):

I just had this same error and, after re-reading the User Guide (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/rds-proxy-setup.html), I discovered my issue was related to Security Groups.

I too am using the same security group for the Proxy and DB, but didn't have both self referential rules set:

1. An outbound rule to itself on port 3306
2. An inbound rule to itself on port 3306

Ensuring I had both of these resolved my issue and I hope will save anyone who reads this a few minutes in resolving it too.

Comment: Thanks a million! In my case I had NACL rules to fight with as well! Reachability analyser is a godsend.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. Adding a 'self referential' security group rule worked for me too.  To elaborate for those who don't know what this means (it wasn't immediately obvious for me).

1. RDS proxy needs a security group inbound rule to accept connections on 3306 from wherever those connections might come from e.g. your ec2 private ip / container / lambda function etc.
2. Your RDS/Aurora instance might need this too if you want direct connections that bypass the proxy
3. The self referential part, is that RDS/Aurora also needs a rule to allow it to accept connections from the proxy. If you're using the same security group for both the proxy & the db instance; the  way to do this is to enter the security group ID  in the inbound rules (instead of an ip address or ip range); e.g. allow inbound on port 3306 from security group sg-123456
4. Both proxy & instance need to send outbound traffic; the default for this is 0.0.0.0/0 (e.g anything, anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can probably do is to create a separate security group for the RDS Proxy.

It is not possible, right now through AWS web console, to create a self reference.